# JSON messages in JMeter with websocket plugin

Tags: json, websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Does anyone know how to configure JSON messages in JMeter when using this websocket [plugin](https://github.com/kawasima/jmeter-websocket)? I found some guides on using JSON messages in JMeter but none seem to correspond with using them with websockets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it would help but you could try this WebSocket plugin for JMeter https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter